# I am having issues collecting the staticfiles in my django application

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to collectstatic files in django using the command `python manage.py collectstaic` but i keep getting the error `The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\Documents\\django\\FIVERR\\Eduo\\OTTO\\staticfiles'`

I have configured the STATICFILES_DIRS but it still doesn't work.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to solve the issue by creating a new empty folder called `staticfiles` in my root application and after running the command again, it collected the staticfiles successfully.